# How to fix "invalid password format or unknown hashing algorithm" error in Django?

Tags: python, django

Have a good day!

I created a custom user model in Django. When I try to create a admin user pofile - all is ok. But when I try to create a simple user profile, I see "invalid password format or unknown hashing algorithm" error in the admin interface. How to fix it?

```
class UserProfileManager(BaseUserManager):

    def create_user(self, email, date_of_birth, password):
        """
        Creates and saves a User with the given email, date of
        birth and password.
        """
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')

        user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            date_of_birth=date_of_birth,
        )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, date_of_birth, password):
        """
        Creates and saves a superuser with the given email, date of
        birth and password.
        """
        user = self.create_user(email,
            password=password,
            date_of_birth=date_of_birth
        )
        user.is_admin = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user


class UserProfile(AbstractBaseUser):
    """
    The user-profile model
    """

    MALE = 'MALE'
    FEMALE = 'FEMALE'
    GENDER = (
        (MALE, 'Male'),
        (FEMALE, 'Female'),
    )

    email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name='email address',
        max_length=255,
        unique=True,
    )
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    # The additional attributes we wish to include.

    # The user's last name
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    # The user's first name
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    # The user's middle name
    middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    # The user's birthday
    date_of_birth = models.DateField()
    # Gender
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=6, choices=GENDER, default=MALE)
    # The user's profile image
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_images', blank=True)
    # Country
    country = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    # City
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    # The user's full address
    address = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    # The institution where the user works or studies
    institution = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    # The user's job
    job = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    # The user's registration date
    registration_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now())
    # How many tests complete this user and how many tests created this user.
    rating = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    objects = UserProfileManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['date_of_birth']

    def get_full_name(self):
        # The user is identified by their email address
        return self.email

    def get_short_name(self):
        # The user is identified by their email address
        return self.email

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        "Does the user have a specific permission?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        "Does the user have permissions to view the app `app_label`?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        "Is the user a member of staff?"
        # Simplest possible answer: All admins are staff
        return self.is_admin

class UserCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):

    password1 = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Password confirmation', widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('email', 'date_of_birth')

    def clean_password2(self):
        # Check that the two password entries match
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")
        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords don't match")
        return password2

    def save(self, commit=True):
        # Save the provided password in hashed format
        user = super(UserCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user


class UserChangeForm(forms.ModelForm):

    password = ReadOnlyPasswordHashField()

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('email', 'password', 'date_of_birth', 'is_active', 'is_admin')

    def clean_password(self):
        # Regardless of what the user provides, return the initial value.
        # This is done here, rather than on the field, because the
        # field does not have access to the initial value
        return self.initial["password"]
```

Answer (score 0):

When I tried to create new user, I used get_or_created method. But I forgot to override it.
Now it works!))

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password
...
def create_user(self, email, date_of_birth, password):
    """
    Creates and saves a User with the given email, date of
    birth and password.
    """
    if not email:
        raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')

    user = self.model(
        email=self.normalize_email(email),
        date_of_birth=date_of_birth,
    )

    user.set_password(make_password(password))
    user.save(using=self._db)
    return user

def create_superuser(self, email, date_of_birth, password):
    """
    Creates and saves a superuser with the given email, date of
    birth and password.
    """
    user = self.create_user(email,
        password=make_password(password),
        date_of_birth=date_of_birth
    )
    user.is_admin = True
    user.save(using=self._db)
    return user

   ...
```